# C++ Can I create an interface which calls method implemented specifically in child class, through operator override implemented in the interface?

Tags: c++

apologies in advance if this question is stupid but:

I have an interface:

```
template <class T>
class IEqualCompare {
public:
    virtual bool IsEqual(const T b) = 0;
    bool operator== (const T b) { return this->IsEqual(b); }     //Both are implemented in cpp file
    bool operator!= (const T b) { return !(this->IsEqual(b)); }
};
```

And a class:

```
class Dimentions : IEqualCompare<Dimentions> {

...


bool IsEqual(const Dimentions b) { //IsEqual logic for this specific class }

...

}
```

I would like to only implement `IsEqual` method for each child class of `IEqualCompare`, as the logic within the operator overloads (==, !=) is the same for any `IEqualCompare` derived class.

Up until now I have always simply defined both operator overrides as virtual and implemented them inside each class, but as the logic should be always the same I wanted to know if this is possible or is it bad programming.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: why do you think it couldn't work?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you gain by doing this, but it should work. I would advise to pass arguments by `const T&` instead of making copies though. In c++20, you can `=default` equality operators.

Comment: I see no problems with your code "this->IsEqual" is identical to writing just "IsEqual" though. You only need to use "this" if there are local variables with the same name, shadowing the class member.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since comparison operators are usually not meant to modify compared objects, they (and `IsEqual` method) should be declared `const` as a general practice of [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). Among other things it helps programmers avoid mistakes of accidentally modifying objects during semantically non-modifying operations and helps optimizers produce more efficient binaries by utilizing more assumptions about code behaviour. Also, to avoid unnecessary copying the argument of operators should generally be taken *by reference*, in our case by *const reference* so that referenced object can't be modified.

Now, if you want to just automatically add equality comparison operators to derived classes based on their `IsEqual` method and not to use dynamic polymorphism/dispatch (it would be pretty pointless for CRTP base), there's no need to make `IsEqual` virtual, or even a member of base class at all. Derived type is provided as template parameter type `T`, so you *statically* know actual (dynamic) object type (this is the whole point of [CRTP pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) you use), thus you can statically cast `this` pointer to `T*` and call non-virtual `IsEqual` method of `T` through resulting pointer avoiding the more costly [virtual dispatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) mechanism. Example:

```
template<typename T>
class AddEqualComparisons {
public:
    bool operator==(const T& b) const { return static_cast<T*>(this)->IsEqual(b); }
    bool operator!=(const T& b) const { return !static_cast<T*>(this)->IsEqual(b); }
};

class Dimensions : public AddEqualComparisons<Dimensions> {
    bool IsEqual(const Dimensions& rhs) const {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not necessarily bad, it is an application of the "template method" design pattern. It does read like C#/Java-style code to me, which is perhaps unconventional in C++ for this purpose.

The convention in C++ has been to just write each `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`. With compilers now supporting C++20, the complementary operator can be generated automatically, removing the need to write a trivial expression like `!(x == y)`. Something like this is often all you need to make your class equality-comparable:

```
class Foo {
    friend bool operator==(Foo const&, Foo const&) = default;  
};
```

If the subobjects of the class (its base classes and member variables) are all [equality_comparable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable), then the above syntax will produce a [default comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) that compares the two sets of subobjects. You can of course create your own definition if you need to deviate from this.

Note that declaring the operator as a non-member friend function is just my preference, the member function syntax is equally valid.